# Target class controller does not exist Laravel 8 in localhost everthing working fine but not online

Tags: php, laravel-8

why does laravel8 work in localserver but not online what do i do flash i get this error message i tried many methods but still got the same problem.
I also edited RouteServiceProvider.php but still didn't change it.
Target class [App\http\Controllers\BookingController] does not exist.

web.php

```
 <?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    use App\http\Controllers\BookingController;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    });
    
    Route::get('/bookings/all',[BookingController::class, 'AllBook'])->name('all.bookings');
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();
        return view('dashboard',compact('users'));
    })->name('dashboard');
```

BookingController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BookingController extends Controller
{
    public function AllBook(){
      $bookings = DB::table('bookings')->latest()->paginate(15);
      return view('admin.skyBookings.index',compact('bookings'));
    }
}
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
     protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the casing in your namespaces and class names.

In your web routes file, you have this line:

```php
use App\http\Controllers\BookingController;
```

But in your actual controller, `Http` starts with a capital letter. So I’m guessing you’re developing on an OS that is case-insensitive (Windows) and deploying to something that *is* case-sensitive (something *nix based).

Comment: @Ayari - Don't forget to select this answer and the upvote button.